# Tags get split when reblogging a post using pytumblr

Tags: python, split, tumblr, pytumblr

When I reblog a post using pytumblr, any tags I pass to the `reblog()` function are split into their constituent letters. For example, the following function call:

```
client.reblog(blogName, id=post['id'], reblog_key=post['reblog_key'],
        state='published', tags='anagram', comment=reblogComment)
```

puts the following tags on the post:

```
#a #n #g #r #m
```

(Note: according to the Tumblr API, tags are to be supplied comma-delineated.)

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: did you try with `tags=('anagram',)` ?, or a list of tags. It looks like an iterable is needed. It is iterating through the tag chars...

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The 'tags' parameter was not in any of the pytumblr documentation I could find. Would you mind making this an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Glad it is solved. Sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `tags=('anagram',)`? Or a list of tags. It looks like an iterable is needed. It is iterating through the tag chars...